# Gradle do not aware about custom autoconfiguration library - tests fails in Gradle, but successful in IDE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, kotlin

I'm creating custom starter and want to add sample application that will demonstrate auto configuration and test it. But it seems that Gradle do not aware about `META-INF/spring.factories` when I run `./gradlew test` in console.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
```

This is my `build.gradle` of the sample application, it is module in multi-module project:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa'
    id 'org.springframework.boot'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':custom-spring-boot-starter')
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation "org.flywaydb:flyway-core:5.2.4"
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.197'
    // Test
    testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:2.1.7.RELEASE'
    testImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.1"
    testImplementation "org.testng:testng:6.14.3"
    testImplementation "com.github.javafaker:javafaker:0.17.2"
    testImplementation "org.awaitility:awaitility:3.0.0"
}

test {
    useTestNG()
    jacoco {
        destinationFile = file("$rootDir/build/jacoco/test.exec")
    }
}
```

It's plain Spring Boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application::class.java, *args)
}
```

And I configure base class for all context tests like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
abstract class ApplicationTest : AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests() {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var restTemplate: TestRestTemplate

    @LocalServerPort
    private var port: Int = 0

    fun getRequest(uri: String, responseType: Class<*>) =
        restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:$port$uri", responseType)
}
```

So, what should I do to apply custom auto configuration under Gradle command execution?

Comment: Looks like you are creating the executable jar yourself in gradle using a custome task  or are you depending on the gradle spring boot plugin ?

Comment: @Shailendra, custom task for creating simple jar. If I try `bootJar` task it will result in error, because starter has no main class.

Comment: `@Autowired` may require a `@Qualifier`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Spring boot multi-module project at official Spring guide [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/) ( source code [here](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-multi-module)) where they have used a custom jar task ("library" module). If you run "`gradle build`" the resulting artifact is in library `module --> libs` folder. This is Spring boot library without main class. The other module ("application")  is of course the main application which uses a simple custom "`bootJar`" task. Both the modules contains tests.